# Azure Service Fabric - change config settings for a deployed Application

Tags: azure-service-fabric

How do I change settings for a deployed application in Service Fabric?

I have a provisioned cluster and an application deployed to the cluster with two applications.  I would like to be able to change my services' settings and have them pick up those changes, but I don't see how I can do that.

Previously, we've done all of our services with worker roles in Cloud Services, and the portal allows for changing configurations, but it does not appear to do so for Service Fabric.  From the Service Fabric Explorer I can drill down to the service, go to MANIFEST and view the XML with the settings.  I just don't see a way to edit or change it.  I've struggled finding anything in the SF documentation addressing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The portal doesn't expose a way to do this.  It needs to be done via an upgrade of the application.  Just change the settings in your settings XML file and perform an upgrade.  In the VS publish dialog for your application project, you can update your version numbers appropriately by changing the config package version which will automatically bubble up to update the containing service and application versions.

Comment: So then, rebuilding the app and doing the update for just the settings only does not force redeploys of any unchanged components?  That's my understanding after reading the articles Ryan Wike linked to in his answer.

Comment: If you're upgrading from Visual Studio, then yes.  Visual Studio automatically generates a "diff package" based on the version differences between what you're deploying and what exists on the cluster.  So if you've only changed the version of the config package, that's all that will be packaged up.  If you're generating a package outside of VS, that won't be the case.

Answer (score 2):

Building on Matt Thalman's answer, here's documentation on modifying the settings in the application or service manifest XML files, updating the version numbers, and performing an application upgrade: [Service Fabric application upgrade tutorial using Visual Studio](https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/service-fabric-application-upgrade-tutorial/).  You can also [perform the app upgrade using PowerShell](https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/service-fabric-application-upgrade-tutorial-powershell/).

Answer (score 1):

Additional to above answers, adding some powershell code..

we may use below powershell code to connect to Service Fabric from powershell and get the application parameters and then update specific parameter and re deploy..

```
### Change the connection here (from Profile-Cloud.xml
$ConnectArgs = @{  
    ConnectionEndpoint="devxxxxxx.westus.cloudapp.azure.com:19000"
    X509Credential="true"
    ServerCertThumbprint="52BFxxxxxxxxxx"
    FindType="FindByThumbprint"
    FindValue="EF3A2xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    StoreLocation="CurrentUser"
    StoreName="My" 
    }
    
Connect-ServiceFabricCluster @ConnectArgs

$myApplication = Get-ServiceFabricApplication -ApplicationName fabric:/ABC.MyService 
$appParamCollection = $myApplication.ApplicationParameters

### Update your parameter here..
$applicationParameterMap.ElasticSearch_Username="sachin2"

$applicationParameterMap = @{}
foreach ($pair in $appParamCollection)
{
    $applicationParameterMap.Add($pair.Name, $pair.Value);
}

### Start Udpating
Start-ServiceFabricApplicationUpgrade -ApplicationName $myApplication.ApplicationName.OriginalString -ApplicationTypeVersion $myApplication.ApplicationTypeVersion -ApplicationParameter $applicationParameterMap -Monitored -FailureAction Rollback -ForceRestart $true

### Check the status until it is Ready 
(Get-ServiceFabricApplication -ApplicationName fabric:/ABC.MyService).ApplicationStatus

### Check the parameters to confirm those're updated 
Get-ServiceFabricApplication -ApplicationName fabric:/ABC.MyService
```

You may change or remove the `-ForceRestart` as per your requriements